# ¿Cómo unir archivos ogg?

Tags: nodejs, bash

Cómo podría ejecutar el equivalente en nodejs el sgte comando en bash.

```
ls | sort -V |xargs cat output.ogg
```

lo que quiero es ordenar una serie de ficheros ogg y unirlos en output.ogg.

ACTUALIZACIÓN

utilice el código que dejarón :

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path="....................RUTA............";


function ordenar(a,b){
    var n=parseInt(a.substr(6,a.indexOf(".ogg")-6));
    var m=parseInt(b.substr(6,b.indexOf(".ogg")-6));
    if(n>m){
    return 1;
    }
    if(n<m){
    return -1;
    }
    else{
    return 0;
    }
}

function dumpData(dirPath, outputFile) {
    // Leer directorio
    fs.readdir(dirPath,function(err, files) {
        if (err) throw err;
        files.sort(ordenar);
        files.forEach(function (file){
            // Filtrar por *.ogg
            if(/^.*\.(ogg)$/.test(file)) {
                // Leer y volcar datos al archivo de salida
                 data = fs.readFileSync(dirPath+"/"+file, 'utf8');
                fs.appendFileSync(outputFile, data);
            }
        });   
    });
}



dumpData(path+'/archivos/principito', 'output.ogg');
```

cuando quiere ejecutarlo con mplayer me sale lo siguiente

```
Playing output.ogg.
Detected file format: MPEG-PES
MPEG: FATAL: EOF while searching for sequence header.
Video: Cannot read properties.
Load subtitles in .
mpg123 init error: Error reading the stream. (code 18)
Audio decoder init failed for codecs.conf entry "mpg123".
ad_ffmpeg: initial decode failed
Audio decoder init failed for codecs.conf entry "ffmp2float".
ad_ffmpeg: initial decode failed
Audio decoder init failed for codecs.conf entry "ffmp2".
Cannot sync MAD frame
Audio decoder init failed for codecs.conf entry "mad".
Cannot sync MPA frame: 0
Audio decoder init failed for codecs.conf entry "hwmpa".
No Libav codec ID known. Generic lavc decoder is not applicable.
Audio decoder init failed for codecs.conf entry "lavc".
Cannot find codec for audio format 0x50.
Audio: no sound
Video: no video


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js cuenta con `fs` para interactuar con el sistema de archivos. La idea es muy similar al comando en bash que utilizas:

1. Mostrar archivos (filtrando por *.ogg)
2. Leer cada archivo
3. Volcar datos al archivo de salida

Aquí una implementación posible:

```
var fs = require("fs");

function dumpData(dirPath, outputFile) {
    // Leer directorio
    fs.readdir(dirPath,function(err, files) {
        if (err) throw err;
        files.forEach(function (file){
            // Filtrar por *.ogg
            if(/^.*\.(ogg)$/.test(file)) {
                // Leer y volcar datos al archivo de salida
                data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
                fs.appendFileSync(outputFile, data);
            }
        });   
    });
}

dumpData('directory/my_oggfiles', 'output.ogg')
```

Es necesario tener en cuenta, cuando es adecuado trabajar de forma **asíncrona** o de forma **síncrona**, pero eso ya sería otro tema a tratar.

Para más información puedes consultar la documentación oficial sobre `fs`:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Saludos.

**EDITO: usando `stream` para mantener el formato**

El código anterior funciona, con texto plano. En este caso, con archivos *.ogg se necesita utilizar [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream). Los streams equivalen a las tuberías en *nix, permiten leer datos de un origen y conectarlo con un destino. Esta sería una posible solución:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function streamFile(files, i, outputFile) {
    if (i == files.length) {
        outputFile.end();
        return;
    }

    stream = fs.createReadStream(files[i++]);
    stream.pipe(outputFile, {end: false});

    stream.on('end', function() {
        streamFile(files, i, outputFile);
    });
}

function appendFiles(dirPath, outputFile) {
    // Leer directorio y filtrar *.ogg
    files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath).filter(function(item) {
        return /^.*\.(ogg)$/.test(item);
    });
    output = fs.createWriteStream('output.ogg');

    // Unir stream
    streamFile(files, 0, output);
}

appendFiles('my_directory/files', 'output.ogg')
```

Saludos.

Comment: hola amigo acabo de hacer lo que dejaste con algunas modificaciones , pero me salta un error cuando quiero ejecutar el archivo con mplayer.

Comment: Hola, no es necesario implementar la función de ordenación que has hecho. `fs.readdir()` ya hace una ordenación natural como `sort -V`. Por otra parte, puedes unir archivos de texto plano... pero no archivos con formato.

Comment: hola si se que hace la ordenación al natural , pero sino hago lo que he hecho , no me lo ordena, no śe porque.

Comment: entonces ¿como podría unir archivos con formato?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta, prueba utilizando streams.

Comment: había hecho algo así pero no me funcionó , veré en que me equivoque.

Comment: amigo me genera el archivo , pero el audio incompleto , solo una pequeña parte diria que es el 0.01% de todo lo que mando,encima entrecortado , intente hacerlo tb con chunks, pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Lo probé con dos archivos .ogg y me funciono. Si no te sirve, deberás buscar herramientas especializadas. Saludos y suerte.

Comment: ya me funcionó creo que fue un mal cacheo ,sin embargo tuve que usar la funcion que puse para ordenar , pues readdir no me lo ordena.